# node.js - connect listner is not getting executed in tcp server

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, chat, tcpserver

I am trying to build a tcp chat server with following code -

```
var net = require("net");

Array.prototype.remove = function(e) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (e == this[i]) { return this.splice(i, 1); }
  }
};

function Client(stream) {
  this.name = null;
  this.stream = stream;
}

var clients = [];

var server = net.createServer(function (stream) {
  var client = new Client(stream);
  clients.push(client);

  stream.setTimeout(0);
  stream.setEncoding("utf8");

  stream.addListener("connect", function () {
    stream.write("Welcome, enter your username:\n");
  });

  stream.addListener("data", function (data) {
    if (client.name == null) {
      client.name = data.match(/\S+/);
      stream.write("===========\n");
      clients.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c != client) {
          c.stream.write(client.name + " has joined.\n");
        }
      });
      return;
    }

    var command = data.match(/^\/(.*)/);
    if (command) {
      if (command[1] == 'users') {
        clients.forEach(function(c) {
          stream.write("- " + c.name + "\n");
        });
      }
      else if (command[1] == 'quit') {
        stream.end();
      }
      return;
    }

    clients.forEach(function(c) {
      if (c != client) {
        c.stream.write(client.name + ": " + data);
      }
    });
  });

  stream.addListener("end", function() {
    clients.remove(client);

    clients.forEach(function(c) {
      c.stream.write(client.name + " has left.\n");
    });

    stream.end();
  });
});

server.listen(7000);
```

But whenever I am trying to connect to this tcp server with

```
nc localhost 7000
```

or

```
telnet localhost 7000
```

connect block is not getting executed.

```
stream.addListener("connect", function () {
        stream.write("Welcome, enter your username:\n");
      });
```

I have also tried to connect to this tcp server with small iOS code but but no luck.

Any idea when/how this connect block will get executed?

Note: I am new to node.js and using mac os x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it should be `connection` event.

The function passed to createServer becomes the event handler for the 'connection' event.

```
var server = net.createServer(function (stream) {
  //if you are here you are already connected
});
```

If you want to listen for `connection` event do it like this -

```
var server = net.createServer(function (stream) {
  //your code
});

server.addListener("connection", function () {
    console.log("connected");    
});
```